# How to get cursor blink on a text box after ajax function page load in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am beginner developer. How can I get the cursor blinking on a text box on page load using the ajax function in jQuery?

Comment: did you try anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```js
$(function(){
  $("#username").focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="username" maxlength="100" />
```

You can use `focus()` to make cursor to focus on an input field. You can use `$("#username").focus();` code anywhere. Now it is used inside `$(function(){})`, so that cursor will focus and blink on the input after the all DOM elements of the page are ready to be used. If you need to do this based on the `ajax call`, then you can put this code inside `success` or `error` or `complete`. If it is inside `success` then the code will execute only if the call is successful. If it is inside `error` then the code will execute only if the call is failed. If it is inside `complete`, then the code will execute always( when the call finishes whether in failure or success). Other options are also available with `jquery ajax call`, for more info [JQuery Ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: While this is correct, it doesn't cover every aspect of the question and will not help the OP unless you explain where to put it and why.  If there's an AJAX call involved then should this run before or after, or do you not care about what the AJAX call does?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `focus()` for the textbox id (see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)).

```
('#username').focus();
```